# Finding a fullstop in a elasticsearch preceeded by wildcard

Tags: database, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have stored my document using whitespace analyzer.Now I want to search for a string like ("*.") but i am unable to find any matches moreover it is unable to find words like ("xyz.") where xyz. exists in the document. Can someone tell the correct query format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with wildcard query something like this ?

```
GET /your_index/your_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "field": "*."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your mapping of that field ?

Comment: I am using elasticseach 6.x, this is the output of GET index_name/_mappings
https://pastebin.com/8JLnxJLr

Comment: Can it be the case that the default stemmer stems the word and the full stop is emitted along with it? since the full stop in document is joined with the preceeding word

Comment: on which field you want to query ?

Comment: Abstract for now would be preferred.

Comment: You said that, you have documents with whitespace analyzer, but I can't see any whitespace analyzer with Abstract field.

Comment: I specified the analyzer as whitespace during the index creation, and then i loaded the data into the index from a csv file using logstash.this is the code for index creation which i used. If there is any discrepancy please guide me to correct it. Thanks   https://pastebin.com/Gj2vC1x1

Comment: Please mention, on which field you have searched ? `Abstract` or `Abstract.keyword` ?

Comment: i have searched on abstract field for now.

Comment: Then Try searching on `Abstract.keyword` field and know me. If it will work then I will explain the thing

Comment: yes it worked..could you explain what was the glitch? i would be glad

Comment: Because your `Abstract` field is text field and by default it is analyzed with standard analyzer. that is the glitch. And you need to search on a field which is not analyzed (analysis which doesn't remove dot ). That's why you need to search on that keyword field. If it helps then please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: ohh fine,does data with keyword field contains raw data without any tokenizer and normalization?  did I use the whitespace analyzer correctly in the snippet provided? I would surely accept your answer.dont worry.

Comment: moreover i want to use span within query to find words within same sentence. To denote a sentence i am using the big field as the *. and small field as the two words provided which i want in the same sentence. I am unsure about how to use the wildcard parameter in the span within.could you please help?

Comment: Yes, `keyword` field contains raw data. As whitespace analyzer doesn't remove dot you can also do that.

Comment: Please ask another question with your problem, basically one question and answer should be specific for that specific question. Hope you understand.

Comment: alright, I would ask another question but was the analyzer written in snippet provided above correct? since it should not eliminate dot being a whitespace analyzer but I cannot find the word ending with the dot in the query on Abstract field. why does that happen?

Comment: Because, analyzer is not applied on that field, put the below mappings. This should work. https://paste.ubuntu.com/26208112/ If it helps accept the answer.